# How-to: add an ISO/DVD of RHEL to the Repository list under Gnome for installing packages

Tags: redhat, yum, rhel5, package-management, repository

I want to add the original ISO I installed RHEL from as a repository under the Add/Remove Software tool in Gnome.

How do I do this?

To clarify, I know *what* I need to do (add a repository) - I need the *how*. I have been unsuccessful in determining the correct string to put in the location field in the Gnome applet. Currently I have `file:///media/rhel/Server/repodata`. I have tried pointing directly to the XML file in that directory, the parent directory, its parent, and in variations with more and less slashes in the path.

**Update**: I found http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/redhat-centos-fedora-linux-setup-repo.html, which has directions for creating the repository manually - but I don't see why this should be needed if the `repomd.xml` file is already on the DVD.

Comment: have you run the createrepo command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey after searching around I was able to find a better understanding answer to this problem.

Make a mount point for your iso:

`mkdir /mnt/pen`

Mount the OS installation iso like normal:

`mount -o loop rhel.iso /mnt/pen/`

Create a details entry for your repository (add a file in the **/etc/yum.repos.d** directory e.g. *rhel.repo*):

> [rhel-cd]
>
> name=Red Hat OS CD
>
> baseurl=file:///mnt/pen/Server
>
> enabled=1
>
> gpgcheck=0

Clean your cache:

`yum clean all`

You should now have your repository visible in Add/Remove Programs.

NOTE: You might want to consider automounting your iso.

Answer (score 2):

Loopmount the iso under `/mnt`, then add a `.repo` file in `/etc/yum.repos.d` whose `baseurl` points to the mountpoint.

Comment: Ignacio - that is the "what", which I know (see original question): I need the "how". Specifically, I am trying to do this with the Gnome "Add/Remove Software" applet. I've added to the question to clarify.

Comment: The correct path is the one that contains the `repodata/` directory. yum looks for its presence in order to find the repo data.

Comment: That is the path I've been trying to add (`/media/rhel/Server/repodata`). The error kicked-back from the applet is "Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: DVD. Please verify its path and try again."

Comment: Contains. Not is. As in, use `/media/rhel/Server`.

Comment: :-\ tried that too, still getting the same error :(

Comment: I think I'll just not worry about it and use `rpm -i` manually.. but it would be nice for it to "just work" (or to be "just setup" like it is with CentOS and all you have to do is enable the line)