# RHN/Yum update from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.0 to 5.1

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, update

I need to update a server from RHEL 5.0 to 5.1

When I use RHN/Yum and do a yum update the 5.0 server gets updated to 5.6

Is there a way to configure RHN/yum to update the server only to RHEL 5.1 ?

In RHN I only see a general "Red Hat Enterprise Linux (v. 5 for 32bit x86)" software channel and not a specific one for the update versions like 5.1

Answer (score 4):

No. 5.1 through 5.5 have come and gone, and only 5.6 remains.

Comment: There can be only one!

Comment: and now only 5.8 :)

Answer (score 4):

As Ignacio said, there's no good way to freeze your install at a specific subversion. In order to have a properly updated system you will have to migrate up to 5.6. However, along the way glibc has been updated, which can result in some issues during the update process. The safest way to update your system will be to run these commands in this order:

1. `yum clean all`
2. `yum update yum`
3. `yum update glibc`
4. `yum update`

Then grab some coffee, a copy of Moby Dick, and come back the following day.

Answer (score 4):

You can update to a specific release by using the DVD.  Mount the 5.1 DVD as a local repo[0] and update with:

```
yum update --noplugins
```

[0] https://access.redhat.com/kb/docs/DOC-9744

Comment: if you don't have an RH login, you can also follow the directions from another question: [How-to: add an ISO/DVD of RHEL to the Repository list under Gnome for installing packages](http://serverfault.com/a/322710/2321)